# Expand Width of Div Class on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a div class wider than it's original size on click of a link; so originally the 'generic-shadow' class is set to 33%, but once i click the 'read-more' i'd like it to be 100%? i'm not too good with jquery/js but hoping i'm close

```js
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  $("generic-shadow").toggleClass("generic-shadow");
  $("generic-shadow").toggleClass("generic-shadow-clicked");
  // hides matched elements if shown, shows if hidden
  $(this).next().toggle();
  $(this).next().next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.generic-shadow {
  height: 100%;
  transition: .8s ease-in-out;
  width: 33%;
}
.generic-shadow-clicked {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="generic-shadow lazy-loading">
  <div class="interactive-pane">

    <div class="pane-overlay"></div>
    <div class="pane-content">
      <div class="pane-title">Integrated Solutions Knowledge &amp; Insight</div>
      <div class="pane-content-inner">
        <img src="images/health-assessments-small.png" alt="Product Logo">
        <h2>Health Assessments</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Read More...</a>

  <div id="content" class="pane">
    <div class="pane-info">Health Assessments serve to determine the current health and wellbeing of your workforce.</div>

  </div>
  <div id="contentHidden" style="display:none;" class="pane">
    <div class="pane-info">
      <p>Health Assessments serve to determine the current health and wellbeing of your workforce.</p>
      <p>Through knowledge and education about an individual’s health, your workers are able to make informed decisions that function to provide a catalyst for positive workplace culture.</p>

      <p><em>Encouraging health, wellbeing and positive workplace culture</em>
      </p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Determine the health of your workforce</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Foster positive lifestyle changes within the workplace</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Educate and empower healthier lifestyle choices</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Provide simple solutions for long-lasting results</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(".generic-shadow").removeClass("generic-shadow");
  $(".generic-shadow").addClass("generic-shadow-clicked");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
$("generic-shadow").toggleClass("generic-shadow");
```

Remove above line and change `$("generic-shadow")` to  `$(".generic-shadow")` as the class needs `.` prefix

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  // $("generic-shadow").toggleClass("generic-shadow");
  $(".generic-shadow").toggleClass("generic-shadow-clicked");
  // hides matched elements if shown, shows if hidden
  $(this).next().toggle();
  $(this).next().next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  // $("generic-shadow").toggleClass("generic-shadow");
  $(".generic-shadow").toggleClass("generic-shadow-clicked");
  // hides matched elements if shown, shows if hidden
  $(this).next().toggle();
  $(this).next().next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.generic-shadow {
  height: 100%;
  transition: .8s ease-in-out;
  width: 33%;
}
.generic-shadow-clicked {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="generic-shadow lazy-loading">
  <div class="interactive-pane">

    <div class="pane-overlay"></div>
    <div class="pane-content">
      <div class="pane-title">Integrated Solutions Knowledge &amp; Insight</div>
      <div class="pane-content-inner">
        <img src="images/health-assessments-small.png" alt="Product Logo">
        <h2>Health Assessments</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Read More...</a>

  <div id="content" class="pane">
    <div class="pane-info">Health Assessments serve to determine the current health and wellbeing of your workforce.</div>

  </div>
  <div id="contentHidden" style="display:none;" class="pane">
    <div class="pane-info">
      <p>Health Assessments serve to determine the current health and wellbeing of your workforce.</p>
      <p>Through knowledge and education about an individual’s health, your workers are able to make informed decisions that function to provide a catalyst for positive workplace culture.</p>

      <p><em>Encouraging health, wellbeing and positive workplace culture</em>
      </p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Determine the health of your workforce</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Foster positive lifestyle changes within the workplace</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Educate and empower healthier lifestyle choices</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Provide simple solutions for long-lasting results</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it hasn't worked though. i think it's because i have 3 blocks (generic-shadow) floating left?

Comment: I have updated the answer and added its snippet. it works. accept and upvote if it is useful